# Process A creates a file through mmap and returns fd. How does process B read the mmap created by process A?

Tags: rust, ipc, mmap

Passing large objects between processes is what I want. There are two process, process A create mmap file, and process B read the mmap.

Process A: Create an object with mmap

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

use std::fs::File;
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;
use bytes::Bytes;
use memmap::Mmap;
use tempfile::tempfile;

#[test]
fn test_tmp_file_mmap() {
    let file = tempfile().unwrap();
    file.set_len(100).unwrap();
    println!("fd = {}", file.as_raw_fd());
    let mmap = unsafe {
        Mmap::map(&file).unwrap()
    };
    let mut_mmap = mmap.make_mut().unwrap();
    // write something into mut_mmap

}

}
```

Cargo.toml

```
memmap = "0.7.0"
tempfile = "3.3.0"
```

I know that the fd of the same file may be different in different processes. But the different fd in multi-process point to the same file in Open File Table of kernel.

Process B：How to get the same mmap in process B using fd of process A (I do not know the file name as I am using `tempfile`)? Or is there any other way to get the mmap of process A without using the filename in rust?

I have seen the code for the c related implementation, but it seems that process B gets mmap directly through process A's fd using `sendmsg`. (I suspect there is some conversion inside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rust equivalent of using C to transmit an `fd` via `sendmsg` already exists in [the `passfd` crate](https://docs.rs/passfd/latest/passfd/). Once the file descriptor is passed, you can make a memory map from it in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is another question for `passfd`.If two processes need to exchange many fds, how to guarantee the order? For example, process A sends fd to process B through send_fd(), but process B hangs at this time. After process B recovers, process A sends another fd to process B. How does process B know that this is the second fd?

Comment: @Christina2333: 1) It's a stream, if B never pulled the first fd, it will still get the fds in order; streams don't just drop data on the floor. 2) It's an arbitrary data-passing conduit where the crate just abstracts away the handling for sending file descriptors; if you need to, you can pass associated metadata (in essentially arbitrary formats) before each fd to assist the other process in handling it properly.